# mongodb how to retrieve all the value in fields type array?

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to retrieve all the values
of a fields type array

ie

```
{ "slug" : "my-post", "status" : "publish", "published" : ISODate("2014-01-26T18:28:11Z"), "title" : "my post", "body" : "my body post", "_id" : ObjectId("52e553c937fb8bf218b8c624"), "tags" : [  "js",  "php",  "scala" ], "created" : ISODate("2014-01-26T18:28:25.298Z"), "author" : "whisher", "__v" : 0 }
{ "slug" : "my-post-2", "status" : "publish", "published" : ISODate("2014-01-26T18:28:27Z"), "title" : "my post 2", "body" : "spost body", "_id" : ObjectId("52e5540837fb8bf218b8c625"), "tags" : [  "android",  "actionscript",  "java" ], "created" : ISODate("2014-01-26T18:29:28.915Z"), "author" : "whisher", "__v" : 0 }
```

the result should be like
"android",  "actionscript",  "java","js",  "php",  "scala"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `distinct` command ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)):

```
> db.test.distinct("tags")
[ "js", "php", "scala", "actionscript", "android", "java" ]
```

You could use aggregation if you eventually needed something more complex:

```
> db.test.aggregate(
         { $project: { tags : 1 } },  
         { $unwind : "$tags" }, 
         { $group : { _id: "$tags" }  }  );
```

Results:

```
[
    {
            "_id" : "java"
    },
    {
            "_id" : "actionscript"
    },
    {
            "_id" : "android"
    },
    {
            "_id" : "scala"
    },
    {
            "_id" : "php"
    },
    {
            "_id" : "js"
    }
]
```

I'd use `$project` ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)) to reduce the number of fields being passed through the pipeline though. In the example above, I've used `$project` to include only the `tags` for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can `$unwind`, and then `$group` them back

```
db.collection.aggregate({ $unwind : "$tags" }, {$group:{_id: "$tags"}});
```

The result would be

```
{ _id: "android"},
{ _id: "actionscript"},
{ _id: "java"},
{ _id: "js"},
{ _id: "php"},
{ _id: "scala"}
```

Comment: > db.posts.aggregate({ $unwind : "$tags" }, {$group:{_id: '$tag'});
...  I see only ...

Comment: FYI: You're missing a `}` at the end of the `$group` and you'd need to group on `'$tags'`.